# Which comes first, Function or Object?

Tags: javascript, function-object, prototype-chain

[image]

There's this Object Layout diagram nicely explains the prototype chain in javascript. But it's a bit confusing to me when it comes to the relationships between the followings:

1. function Object(){}
2. Object.prototype
3. function Function(){}
4. Function.prototype

My question is: Among the above four elements, which comes first? Because I see a cycle among them.

1. function Object.____proto____ -> Function.prototype
2. Function.prototype.____proto____ -> Object.prototype
3. Object.prototype.constructor -> function Object

And also another cycle is:

1. Function.prototype.constructor -> function Function
2. function Function.____proto____ -> Function.prototype

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up two concepts here, one about the `prototype` property of of the native constructors and the actual prototype of instances of these native constructs (represented using `__proto__`). In your first example:

> 1. `function Object.__proto__` -> `Function.prototype`
> 2. `Function.prototype.__proto__` -> `Object.prototype`
> 3. `Object.prototype.constructor` -> `function Object`

You have to understand here that `Object` and `Function` are themselves functions, as constructors are a form of a function.

In #1, `Object` is a function, and the actual prototype of all functions is `Function.prototype`.

In #2, the prototype that function *instances* inherit itself inherits from `Object.prototype`. That means that when you look up the prototype chain from a function instance, it will first look at `Function.prototype`, then `Object.prototype`.

In #3, the `constructor` property is meant for object *instances*, though `Object.prototype` is an object itself. It does not have a prototype.

For your second example:

> 1. `Function.prototype.constructor` -> `function Function`
> 2. `function Function.__proto__` -> `Function.prototype`

What's in the prototype is meant for *instances*, not the actual function constructor itself. Because the constructor of any function is `Function`, that makes sense.

Remember that constructors are still functions? Therefore the prototype of the `Function` *constructor* will be `Function.prototype`. `Function.prototype` itself is an object, so it will have a `__proto__` of `Object.prototype`.

---

When you're looking at actual function instances, here's how properties are looked up through the prototype chain:

```
own properties (on the function itself, functions are special objects)
      |
      |
      ↓
Function.prototype (the __proto__ of the function itself)
      |
      |
      ↓
Object.prototype (the __proto__ of Function.prototype)
      |
      |
      ↓
END (Object.prototype's __proto__ is null)
```